# Converting NSString to JSON with NSJSONSerialization is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I have this function:

```
- (void)checkLogin:(NSString *)pLogin andPassword:(NSString*) pPassword {
    //Create the data object.
    NSMutableDictionary *tLoginAndPasword = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:pLogin,@"Login",pPassword,@"Password", nil];
    NSMutableDictionary *tData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[_Util serializeDictionary:tLoginAndPasword],@"Data", nil];
    //Call the login method.
    NSData *tResponse = [_Util getLogin:tData];
    if (tResponse != Nil) {
        _oLabelErrorLogin.hidden = YES;
        [_Util setUser:pLogin andPassword:pPassword];
        NSMutableDictionary *tJSONResponse =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tResponse options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        NSString *tPayload = [tJSONResponse objectForKey:@"Payload"];
        if([[tJSONResponse objectForKey:@"StatusCode"]  isEqual: @"424"]) {
            //Set global values.
            NSData *tPayloadData = [tPayload dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:tPayloadData]) {
                _Payload = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tPayloadData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
                _RowCount = _Payload.count;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"JSON Wrong String %@",tPayload);
            }
        } else if([[tJSONResponse objectForKey:@"StatusCode"]  isEqual: @"200"]){
            _Payload = Nil;
        }
    } else {
        //Set global values.
        _Payload = Nil;
        _oLabelErrorLogin.hidden = NO;
        //Clear login data.
        _oLogin.text = @"";
        _oPassword.text = @"";
        [_Util setUser:@"" andPassword:@""];
    }
}
```

The JSON response looks like this:

```
{
  "Payload": "{\"UserName\":\"Marco Uzcátegui\",\"Clients\":[{\"UserProfileId\":4,\"ProfileName\":\"Platform Administrator\",\"ClientName\":\"Smart Hotel Platform\",\"InSession\":true},{\"UserProfileId\":5,\"ProfileName\":\"Administrator\",\"ClientName\":\"La Moncloa de San Lázaro\",\"InSession\":false},{\"UserProfileId\":6,\"ProfileName\":\"Administrator\",\"ClientName\":\"Jardín Tecina\",\"InSession\":false}]}",
  "StatusCode": "424",
  "StatusDescription": null
}
```

As you can see, I have a escaped string inside "Payload" that is a correct JSON, so I want to generate another NSMutableDictionary with that string, so I'm doing this:

```
NSData *tPayloadData = [tPayload dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:tPayloadData]) {
    _Payload = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tPayloadData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    _RowCount = _Payload.count;
} else {
    NSLog(@"JSON Wrong String %@",tPayload);
}
```

So I'm creating an NSData from the NSString and asking if is valid, it always returns false.

I have tried to replace the "\" from the string and is not working.

```
[tPayload stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@""]
```

I have tried to create a NSMutableDictionary with the string, but the result is not a dictionary.

```
NSMutableDictionary *tPayload = [tJSONResponse objectForKey:@"Payload"];
```

I'm kind of lost here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: @luk2302 the problem is that the JSON response is stringify, at the office we do this all the time with JavaScript and C# but I'm having problems with iOS

Comment: @luk2302 here you have a better explanation of what we do: http://www.allannienhuis.com/archives/2015/02/04/beware-json-stringify/

Comment: I just wrote a test program that deserializes your example string.  Works just fine.  I did notice that the embedded unicode escapes were not decoded.  Probably have to unescape those first.

Comment: Interestingly, the call to `isValidJSONObject` does return false.  Apparently, that method is buggy.  My advice would be to just call `JSONObjectWithData::` and check the error afterward.

Comment: @Avi can you post some code because I tried to pass the string write by me [@"{\"UserName\":\"Marco Uzcátegui\",\"Clients\":[{\"UserProfileId\":4,\"ProfileName\":\"Platform Administrator\",\"ClientName\":\"Smart Hotel Platform\",\"InSession\":true},{\"UserProfileId\":5,\"ProfileName\":\"Administrator\",\"ClientName\":\"La Moncloa de San Lázaro\",\"InSession\":false},{\"UserProfileId\":6,\"ProfileName\":\"Administrator\",\"ClientName\":\"Jardín Tecina\",\"InSession\":false}]}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; and it did not work

Comment: I'll post to pastebin and edit this comment to include the link. // edit // http://pastebin.com/e2w4rsN0.  Ignore the unrelated bits.  I have a test file that I throw stuff into.

Comment: @luk2302: There is nothing wrong with the JSON string. It's just a literal JSON string as a dictionary value.

Comment: @vadian I did realize that by now - but it still is not a dictionary as desired.

Comment: @luk2302 I just checked it in a Playground (Swift is so much easier to play with), it is a correct dictionary with 2 keys `UserName` (String) and `Clients`  (Array)

Comment: @vadian Hmm, okay, do not see why, but if you say so. Those Json question are always ugly to deal with due to the escaping of the actual string, the output, etc. :/

Comment: @luk2302 The string is enclosed in double quotes (as expected) and all JSON double quotes inside are escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line

```
[NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:tPayloadData]
```

From the documentation of `isValidJSONObject`

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given object can be
>   converted to JSON data.

*given object* means an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` but **not** `NSData`

Remove that check and implement the error parameter in `JSONObjectWithDataoptions:error:`

Answer (score 1):

The method `NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject:` checks if an object (e.g. a `NSDictonary` or `NSArray` instance) can be converted **to** JSON. It doesn't check if a `NSData` instance can be converted **from** JSON. For `NSData`, it will always return false.

So just call `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData:options:` and check the result instead.